# Fill array in two dimensional array at a specific index using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to fill inner array of two dimensional array with items at specific index. The problem in this case is that every inner array is filled with that items.

Try: [link_to_code_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nZXD.jpg)

Result: [link_to_result_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG9bz.png)

the code:

```
Array.prototype.repeat= function(what, L){
  while(L) this[--L]= what;
  return this;
};

var yearsdays = [].repeat([], 365);

for(var i = 0; i<= yearsdays.length; i++){
   if(i === 99) {
      yearsdays[i].push(99)
   }
}
```

the result:

```
Array[365]
  [0 … 99]
     0: Array[1]
       0: 99
       length: 1
       __proto__: Array[0]

     1: Array[1]
       0: 99
       length: 1
       __proto__: Array[0]

     2: Array[1]
       0: 99
       length: 1
       __proto__: Array[0]

     and etc.......
```

The problem is that as a result every array in yearsdays was filled with number 99, but not only array with index 99 as I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your inner arrays are all references of each other.

Comment: Please don't extend built-in prototypes.

Comment: @gcampbell why not?

Comment: @jackjop I should correct that to say "Please don't extend built-in prototypes, except from a centralised point and never as part of a library for other people to use."

Comment: @jackjop What if the next version of the browser has its own method with the same name? Your extension will override it, which could break things.

Comment: I see, it should be better to do simple repeat([], 365); then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the same array to the `repeat` function. So it is going to be 365 references to a single array.

A correct way to do this is:

```
Array.prototype.repeat= function(L){
      while(L) this[--L]= new Array();
      return this;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As Redu stated in the comments

> Your inner arrays are all references of each other

You can get away from this problem like this. It somehow clones the array so the references are different.

```
Array.prototype.repeat= function(what, L){
  while(L) this[--L]= what.slice(0); // <--- Here
  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate a proper 2D array all nested array items should be unique. Due to objects being reference types in JS you have to be ceraful when generating multi-dimensional arrays in JS. One possible and generic way of creating a multi-dimensional array is;

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = Array.isArray(c) ? c.clone() : c, p),[])
}

function arrayND(...n){
  return n.reduceRight((p,c) => c = (new Array(c)).fill(true).map(e => Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone() : p ));
}

yearsdays = arrayND(365,1,0);
yearsdays[6][0]="Sunday";
console.log(yearsdays);
```